# What will be the regex for "Abc-123" in JS

Tags: regex

I am unable to find exact regex for "Abc-123" that is alphabets(Abc...), dash (-), number(0-9) in JS. What have I create so for now is:

```
[a-zA-Z]-[0-9]+$.
```

Last part of numbers works fine but first part before dash didn't work fine because it also accepts numbers withing string which is not required. Alphabets and numbers can be at any length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want the quantifier `+`. `\d` is same as `[0-9]`

```
/^[a-z]+-\d+$/i
```

Comment: @Jahangir glad to have helped :) Do mark it as answer by clicking on the tick mark